# onpage in typo3 with sr_include_pages extension

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I want to make a one page site with typo3

Normally i used the include_pages extension, but with my installed typo3 6.0.12 I am not able to add the extension.

I get an error if I want to install the extension:

> Abhängigkeiten konnten nicht aufgelöst werden
>   Your PHP version is higher than allowed. You can use PHP versions 0.0.5 - 0.0.5

Can anybody help me with this error. Or may have somebody a alternative to make a one page site.

Answer (score 0):

The extension has a wrong PHP dependency set in its ext_emconf.php:

```
'PHP_version' => '0.0.5-0.0.5',
```

I suggest you download the ZIP version of the extension from http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/sr_include_pages, unpack it to your typo3conf/ext directory, edit the ext_emconf.php and remove this line completely. You should then be able to install it.

Please keep in mind that this doesn't mean that it still works on 6.0. But as far as I can see after taking a quick look, it should work in 6.0 and 6.1 (but not in 6.2).